# How to reduce thread switching latency in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a Python 2.7 app that has 3 producer threads and 1 consumer thread that are connected to a `Queue.queue`. I'm using `get` and `put`, and the producer threads spend most of their time blocked in IO (reading from serial ports) - basically doing nothing. Basically calling `serial.read()`...

However, I seem to have what I would call a high latency between the time a producer thread **puts** to the queue and the time the consumer thread **gets** from the queue, like 25 ms (I'm running a 1 processor Beagle Bone Black  (1GHz) on Angstrom Linux).

I would think that if all the processes are blocked, then the elapsed time between **put** and **get** should be really small, a few microseconds or so, not tens of milliseconds, except when the consumer thread is actually busy (which is not the case here).

I've read some things online that suggest that Python is guilty of busy spin, and that the GIL in Python is to blame. I guess I would rather not know the reason and just get something that is more responsive. I'm fine with the actual latency of serial transmission (about 1-2 ms).

The code looks basically like

```
q = Queue.queue

def a1(): 
   while True:
      p = read_serial_packet("/dev/ttyO1")
      p.timestamp = time.time()
      q.put(p)

def a2(): 
   while True:
      p = read_serial_packet("/dev/ttyO2")
      p.timestamp = time.time()
      q.put(p)

def a3(): 
   while True:
      p = read_serial_packet("/dev/ttyO3")
      p.timestamp = time.time()
      q.put(p)

def main():
   while True:
      p = q.get()
      d = time.time() - p.timestamp
      print str(d)
```

and there are 4 threads running `a1`, `a2`,`a3` and `main`.

Here are some sample times

```
0.0119640827179
0.0178141593933
0.0154139995575
0.0192430019379
0.0185649394989
0.0225830078125
0.018187046051
0.0234098434448
0.0208261013031
0.0254039764404
0.0257620811462
```

Is this something that is "fixed" in Python 3?

Comment: You can try putting a `time.sleep(0)` in your producers to have them yield control of the GIL immediately.

Comment: @roippi - thanks for the idea, but it doesn't seem to affect the answer much. I inserted `time.sleep(0)` after the `q.put()`.  Latencies are still 0.013 to 0.028 seconds.  It might have shaved off a few milliseconds.

Comment: Have you tried timing time.time()? Sometimes just asking for the time can waste milliseconds (depending on the time function and the OS). It might be worth removing the granular timing information and performing an overall benchmark. Also, it might be worth looking at 'multiprocess' module of python, rather than using threads.

Comment: @Alp - The consumer thread is only doing `p.get()` while I am doing the timing experiment. I'm measuring the time between `put()` and `get()`, not the time between `get()` and `get()` which would include the time to work on the received object.

Comment: `time.time()` on this platform seems reasonable. It may not be nanosecond accurate, but back-to-back calls give differences on the microsecond scale.  I am consistently getting 10s of millisecond deltas.

Comment: @Mark - You mistook my point.  It doesn't matter if the consumer is only doing `p.get()`.  What matters is how long that takes _relative to_ how frequently items are being enqueued.  If those rates are of the same order of magnitude, you'll see non-trivial times between `put()` and `get()`.

Comment: @Alp - I see what you mean. I forgot to mention that in this example, the other threads (a2,a3) are not doing anything. I only put those threads in the example to motivate the need for the thread safe queue, but in reality, those threads are idle. It is really just `a1` feeding `main`.

Comment: @fileoffset - I think your suggestion to use `multiprocess` is right on the mark. I tried it (easier than I thought!) and the latencies are now 2-3 ms.

Comment: No worries :) Glad you got it solved

Answer (score 2):

As @fileoffset hinted, the answer seems to be switching from `threading` (which suffers from the fact that the Python GIL does not actually do "real" threading) to `multiprocessing`, which has several python processes instead of threads.

The conversion from threading to multiprocessing looks like this:

```
useMP = True  # or False if you want threading

if useMP:
    import multiprocessing
    import multiprocessing.queues
    import Queue # to import Queue.Empty exception, but don't use Queue.Queue
else:
    import threading
    import Queue

...


    if useMP:
        self.event_queue = multiprocessing.queues.Queue()
        t1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.upstream_thread)
        t2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.downstream_thread)
        t3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.scanner_thread)
    else :
        self.event_queue = Queue.Queue()
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=self.upstream_thread)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=self.downstream_thread)
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=self.scanner_thread)
```

The rest of the API looks the same.

There is one other important issue though that was not easy to migrate and is left as an exercise. The issue is catch Unix signals, such as SIGINT or Ctrl-C handlers. Previously, the master thread catches the signal and all the other threads ignore it. Now, the signal is sent to *all* processes. So you have to be careful about catching `KeyboardInterrupt` and installing signal handlers. I don't think I did it the right way, so I am not going to elaborate... :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try playing around with the value of the ["check interval"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setcheckinterval)

```
sys.setcheckinterval(50)
```

A brief explanation of the general concept can be found in [these slides](http://www.dabeaz.com/python/UnderstandingGIL.pdf), starting around page 10.